# WatchOS 2.1 HMAccessory show as reachable when it's not

Tags: ios, watchos-2, homekit

In WatchOS 2.1, Calling `HMAccessory` parameter `reachable` return `YES`.
Then calling `writeValue` to a characteristic, return error:
`Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=4 "Accessory is not reachable." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Accessory is not reachable.}`

This works fine with iOS 9, but not with the WatchOS.
I'm testing on an actual Apple watch, not simulator.